# Showing and hiding divs on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have a nav bar with 3 menu points. called "home" "bildformate" and "kontakt". On load the a div with the class "home" is displayed below the navbar, displaying text etc. The other 2 divs are hidden. When I click on "bildformate" I want the home div to disappear and the div with the class "formate" should be visible. Same goes for the div "kontakt". But lets focus on the "bildformate" div first. This is my code right now:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bildformate').click(function() {
        // show and hide
        $('.home').hide();
        $('.formate').show();   
    });
});
```

So when i click "bildformate" it works for like a split of a second. You can see the "home" div becoming invisible and the "formate" div flahes for second. Then everything looks like before. Why?

CSS of the 3 divs:

```
.home {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 30px;
width: 60%;
padding: 0px;
background-color:#ededed;
color: #787878;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.formate {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 30px;
width: 60%;
padding: 0px;
background-color:#ededed;
color: #787878;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.kontakt {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 30px;
width: 60%;
padding: 0px;
background-color:#ededed;
color: #787878;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.content {
margin: 40px;
padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<body> 
<nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="bildformate.html">Home</a></li>              
        <li class="bildformate"><a href="">Bildformate</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="home">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Willkommen</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formate">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Bildformate</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="kontakt">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Kontakt</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain clearer? On load, you see div2 only (according to the css). And after you click ".trigger", you should see only div1 (according to the js). So what are you seeing instead?

Comment: On load I see one div displaying some text. There are 3 buttons wich display one div each. So on load one div is visible and when I click teh trigger and want to the first div to disappear and the 2nd div to appear. Same goes for the other two buttons. This example shows what should happen if I want to display div1. div2 and div3 should be hidden then.

Comment: Please include html code too it will help alot

Comment: I just added the html code.

Comment: "On load I see one div displaying some text." is vague. Which DIV? What text? And your HTML code doesn't even have an element with class "trigger", so your jQuery click handler should do nothing for "trigger".  And you talk about three buttons in your comments, but I don't see a single button in your HTML...

Comment: Ok, I am german and I changed all these terms in here so you guys can follow the context a bit better. Sorry, it looks like I miscalled some of these terms. So. I am going to edit the whole question and you can check it again. My problem is actually pretty simple. Give me a minute.

Comment: Okey, my problem should be very clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the problem your links, `<a..` tags have their `href` attribute set as `''` which causes page to reload for you.

If you change them to `<a href="#" ...` instead then it wont reload. The reset/flash thing you speak of is the result of page reloading and thus bringing everything to original state.

For testing i just wrote this line

```
$("a").attr("href", "#");
```

However you should manually go change all href attributes to # value.

Comment: Alright! That worked. I totally forgot about the links. I mean I don't need them anymore. Thanks for the kind help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have some trouble showing and hiding some divs.
Here is shown & hide example:

```js
var toggle = false;
$('#press').click(function() { //Our button and on press
  if (toggle) { //check if its hidden
    $('.first').show();
    toggle = false;
  } else {
    $('.first').hide();
    toggle = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.first {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: pink;
}
.second {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: teal;
}
.third {
  border: 2px dotted green;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="press">Show</button>
<div class="first">This is the first div</div>
<div class="second">Second div here</div>
<div class="third">etc</div>
```

If you want less code you can simply toggle it:

```js
$('#press').click(function() {
  //when pressed
  $('.first').toggle(); // show and hide
});
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="press">Toggle instead</button>
<div class="first">This is the first example</div>
<div class="second">Just a placeholder</div>
```

Comment: This is what I tried but the second dif just flashes for a second and tehn disappears again.